# Blue card - Work Visa Germany

Tags: working-visas, germany, blue-card

I received my national Type D visa from the Germany consulate, the process was only one week.

While submitting my documents to the consulate, the lady there told me that my university as per anabin is H+/- but since i'm going to Germany with the same company she accepted to receive the documents and told me that no need to be recognized and she said that i'm eligible to apply for Blue Card.

My question is when i apply for blue card in Germany, do They still require my University degree recognition?

Since i have the visa already, is there possibility that my blue card to be rejected in Germany?

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Blue Card requires a recognised university degree. This is the main requirement for the Blue Card. Otherwise one might be still eligible to apply for a [regular residence permit for the purpose of employment](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/21060/13223).