# What should I do to benefit from my spouse's Blue Card?

Tags: germany, working-visas, resident-permit, blue-card, dependent-visa

I’m a **non-EU** citizen who just moved to Germany with a **D-Type Visa** and I started working 2 weeks ago. My visa is valid until February 2021. I didn’t get my residence permit yet. I have visited the Foreigners Office (*Ausländerbehörde*) but they didn’t accept my application and gave me an appointment in January 2021.

My wife is also a **non-EU** citizen living in Germany since September 2019. She was working with a regular work permit. She received her **Blue Card** recently.

My question is, am I allowed to apply for the Blue Card since my wife has it? 
I want to get it because there is always a possibility of getting fired and my visa is dependent on my current work.

Comment: Blue Card is absolutely the same in this sense, i.e., first two years it is also dependent on current work. This answer might be very relevant for your situation: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/21060/13223

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you may not apply for a Blue Card  because your spouse has one.
You can only apply for a Blue Card if you yourself fulfill the Blue Card conditions.

A spouse of a residence permit holder can apply for a dependent residence permit based on [§ 27 AufthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0726). Such permits are generally issued in 1 year periods (§27(4)).

Exceptions exist for certain residence permit types of the spouse, where the validity of the dependent residence permit matches that of the spouses permit

- Researchers, Blue/ICT Cards and EU long term residence of other member states

---

**Sources**:

- [§ 27 AufthG - Subsequent immigration of dependants](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0726)